# How to import dygraphs back into R?

Tags: shiny, dygraphs

I'm saving a dygraph with the saveWidget and then want to load it back into the ui.R of a shiny app with includeHTML. In short, in the server.R I put:

```
saveWidget(p,"html/dyplot.html")
```

in the ui.R:

```
includeHTML("html/dyplot.html")
```

Currently this does not work, could somebody point me in the right direction here?

Comment: why not simply create your dygraph plot in your shiny app (https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html)

Comment: the calculations behind the dygraph can take a few minutes. in the meantime I want to display the 'old' graph. the detour of exporting and re-importing the html object ensures that the 'old' graph is only replaced when the new one has been calculated and saved. also when starting the app you don't have to wait 2 minutes, but directly see the 'old' graph.